# AppHarbor doesn't forward Headers with _ on the Header name

Tags: http-headers, appharbor

I'm using AppHarbor and had a problem where none my users where being authenticated due to the fact that the CRSF (Cross-Site-Request-Forgery) check was failing.

I found out that the problem was that the custom CRSF_Header used was not being forwarded to my AppHarbor (even though other custom headers were)

It turns out that the problem is that Headers with _ (underscore) on the name are not forwarded by AppHarbor internal proxies.

The fix was then to rename the header name from CRSF_Header to CRSF-Header.

My question is: **Is there another way to do this? or I have to avoid _ on headers when using AppHarbor.**

Note that IIS and Cassini had no probs with these headers (so far I only had this problem in AppHarbor)

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found this AppHarbor article that confirms it: http://support.appharbor.com/discussions/problems/5442-custom-http-header-not-reaching-the-application

Annoyingly AppHarbor discussion search wasn't working properly when I had this issue since I didn't saw that article when searched for it